# reading from stdin in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to read from stdin using C++, using this code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    while(cin) {
        getline(cin, input_line);
        cout << input_line << endl;
    };
    return 0;
}
```

when i compile, i get this error..

```
[root@proxy-001 krisdigitx]# g++ -o capture -O3 capture.cpp
capture.cpp: In function âint main()â:
capture.cpp:6: error: âinput_lineâ was not declared in this scope
```

Any ideas whats missing?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You have not defined the variable `input_line`.

Add this:

```
string input_line;
```

And add this include.

```
#include <string>
```

Here is the full example. I also removed the semi-colon after the while loop, and you should have `getline` inside the while to properly detect the end of the stream.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @KerrekSB - `return 0` may be implied, but that's a nasty wart that was inherited from C.  Much better to be explicit.

Comment: @MartinBonner: Disagree.  Implicit return 0 on main is fine.

Answer (score 4):

```
//declaration:    
    int i2;
    double d2;
    string s2;
//reading by keyboard

    cin >> i2;
    cin >> d2;
    cin.get();
    getline(cin, s2);
//printing:
    cout << i+i2 << endl;    
    cout<< std::fixed <<std::setprecision(1)<< d + d2 << endl;
    cout << s << s2;
```

you can run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    string s = "hi ";
    

    int i2;
    double d2;
    string s2;
    cin >> i2;
    cin >> d2;
    cin.get();
    getline(cin, s2);
    cout << i+i2 << endl;
    cout<< std::fixed <<std::setprecision(1)<< d + d2 << endl;
    cout << s << s2;

    return 0;
}
```