# How to store a single word in a vector ? (c++)

Tags: c++, string, vector, char

**Idea:**
I'm trying to create a program that searches for user-entered-word in a .txt file. Size of the word is not given. I want to find a way to dynamically store user's word to be able to compare it to the other words from file.

The entire program is huge so i only attach a part related to my queasions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <vector> 
#include <string>

    void vectorfill(vector<char>& newword) //filling char vector
    {
        char input;
        scanf_s("%c", &input);
        while (input != -1)
        {
            newword.push_back(input);
            scanf_s("%c", &input);
        }
    }

int main (void)
{
    vector<char> word; 
    printf("Enter a word: (-1 to finish)");
    vectorfill(word);    
}
```

**Questions:**

**1)** Is char vector a best idea in this case ?

**2)** (In case we're good with char vector)How to make compiller understand that user finished writing their word? Can we ask him to put (-1) at the end? Is there a better way to mark the end of the input?

Comment: You should use vector<string>, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464344/reading-from-stdin-in-c

Comment: And `while (input != -1)`, that doesn't do what you think it does. :-)

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how to use `std::string` and `std::getline()`, then read it. This is C++. There's no need to jump through hoops using awkward C library functions like `scanf` and friends, when far more sophisticated and convenient C++ library functions like `std::getline`() will do a far better job.

Comment: You have to decide whether you write C or C++ - these are different languages with different solutions. In C++ you could use `std::string` to store the word and `std::cin` to read a line from console standard input.

Comment: Use a string to store the user's word. Separate the file into a vector of string words and check if the vector contains the user's word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1> No. Use a `std::string`

2> Yes. Use whitespace.

Example:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    std::string word; 
    std::cout << "Enter a word" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> word;
    // do something with word. For example, 
    std::cout << "You entered" << word << '\n';
}
```

As soon as the user types in at least one number, letter, or other non-[whitespace character](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) followed by a whitespace character a word will have been captured in `word`. If you have special requirements like this word can only contain letters (no numbers, bells, ASCII art characters, etc...) a simple loop with [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) can sort that out in a few lines of code, but not as few as [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and `isalpha`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but my program doesn’t do any hing when i write “something(spacebar)”. Then it closes upon hitting enter. What’s wrong?

Comment: This example only shows how to get the data in. It doesn't do anything with it. Will update.

Answer (score 0):

If the searching content is in txt file. Using `std::vector<std::string>` may be better. You can use the split char to split the words.

If the content is from user's keyboard input. you can also use `std::string` to store every word typed, and store it in `std::vector<std::string>`. Just like this:

```
std::string s;
std::vector<std::string> vec;
std::cout << "Please enter somestring" << std::endl;
while (cin >> s)
{
    vec.push_back(s);
    cout << "You have entered : " << s << endl;
}
```